# Pandas Multiindex Cross-section

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

How to select data from multiple different indices?
My data looks like in the picture below.
[image: Given]

If I use the command

```
df_extract = df.xs((0,21), level=('ID','JI'), axis=1)
```

I get the following result and it works as intended.

[image: Extraction]

I am now wondering how to achieve a similar result with multiple different indicies, e.g. if I want to get all data with ID=0 and JI=21 **and also** JI=20 meaning the number of columns would double.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`slicers`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
np.random.seed(1235)

a = ['RX','confidence']
b = range(4)
c = range(22)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b,c])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 176), columns=mux)
```

---

```
print (df)
         RX                                                              \
          0                                                               
         0         1         2         3         4         5         6    
0  0.689382 -0.031712  0.668054  0.488838 -0.679788 -1.307479  1.470304   
1 -0.036204  1.160644 -0.732690  1.236523 -3.056192 -0.934713  1.710129   
2  1.053523 -0.155585  2.366245 -0.881146  1.020934 -0.864370 -0.296776   
3  0.400810 -0.684544 -0.834513 -2.430665 -1.235054  1.267301  0.733521   
4 -0.948905 -2.201098 -0.817812  1.668433 -0.262451 -0.898930 -0.322147   

                                   ...    confidence                      \
                                   ...             3                       
         7         8         9     ...            12        13        14   
0 -1.231027  0.958775  0.740490    ...     -1.566432 -1.100071  0.798843   
1 -0.672050  0.266822  1.721244    ...      1.283321 -0.881721 -1.681788   
2 -0.516580  1.273032  0.390264    ...      1.509285  0.901942  0.075606   
3  0.593818 -0.254829 -0.160123    ...     -0.535404 -1.354794  0.981214   
4 -1.746534  0.933562  2.149050    ...     -2.636260  0.761145 -0.629726   



         15        16        17        18        19        20        21  
0  0.263073 -0.343827 -0.567384 -0.118225  1.285035 -1.111085 -0.696510  
1 -1.151469 -0.487992  0.499224  0.613910 -1.581301 -0.354810  1.045596  
2  0.248246 -2.444664  0.853859  0.503577  0.804451 -0.684316  1.557988  
3 -0.770024 -0.685887  0.767945 -1.050074  0.794344  0.132869 -0.824384  
4 -1.983435  0.789378  2.411277  2.603050  0.433517  0.918651 -1.088107  

[5 rows x 176 columns]
```

---

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df = df.loc[:, idx[:, 0, [20,21]]]
print (df)
         RX           confidence          
          0                    0          
         20        21         20        21
0 -0.680341  0.338532  -0.701041 -1.263422
1 -0.571725  0.081422   0.385731 -0.306937
2  0.131121 -0.889890   0.245415  0.686879
3  0.839858  0.145986  -0.391957  1.029721
4 -1.278226  0.877223  -0.579988 -0.398001
```